# How to upload images to separate folders?

Tags: image, server, directory, upload

How can I upload images inserted in form to server that each new upload will create new folder in main directory and name it for example i1, i2, i3...?

Now my uploadings is saving to main folder, so I need to separate it.

```
$targetDir = "images/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function to create a folders, and add it to your php code

```
if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
    mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}
```